# How can I add these information at the titlepage?

Tags: pdftex, titles, koma-script, thesis

How can I add the name of university and the name of supervisor at the title page of my thesis?

Do I have to add a command before or after `\maketitle`?

```
\begin{document} 

\title{ Blabla } 

\author{ Blabla } 

\date{ } 

\maketitle
```

**EDIT:**

I wrote the following:

```
\begin{document} 

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}

\HRule \\[2cm] % Horizontal line
{\huge \bfseries BLaBLa}\\[0.4cm] % Thesis title
\HRule \\[3cm] % Horizontal line

\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth} 
\begin{center}
 \Large{Name} 
\end{center}
\end{minipage}\\[2cm] 


\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth} 
\begin{center}
\Large
\emph{Επιβλέπων καθηγητής:} 
{name}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}\\[2cm]

\textsc{\Large Μεταπτυχιακή εργιασία}\\[2cm] % Thesis type 

\textsc{\LARGE blabla}\\[0.4cm] 
\textsc{\LARGE University}\\[2cm] % University name

{\large \today}\\[4cm] 

\vfill
\end{center}

\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

but I get the following error for the line

```
\HRule \\[2cm] % Horizontal line
{\huge \bfseries BLaBLa}\\[0.4cm] % Thesis title
\HRule \\[3cm] % Horizontal line
```

[image]

What does this mean?

Comment: [How to customize my titlepage?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/209993)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a new command `\HRule` to print a horizontal rule with

```
\newcommand*{\HRule}{\hrule height 5pt}
```

You can change the numer after `height` to get a lower or higher rule.

Your command for a new line with special space to the next line `\\[2cm]` does then not work.  Instead use the command `\vspace{2cm}`.

With that changes your code compiles with:

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=true]{scrreprt}

\newcommand*{\HRule}{\hrule height 5pt} % <===========================


\begin{document} 

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}

\HRule  % <===========================
\vspace{2cm} % <===========================
{\huge \bfseries BLaBLa}\\[0.4cm] % Thesis title
\HRule  % <===========================
\vspace{3cm} % <===========================

\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth} 
\begin{center}
 \Large{Name} 
\end{center}
\end{minipage}\\[2cm] 


\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth} 
\begin{center}
\Large
\emph{Επιβλέπων καθηγητής:} 
{name}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}\\[2cm]

\textsc{\Large Μεταπτυχιακή εργιασία}\\[2cm] % Thesis type 

\textsc{\LARGE blabla}\\[0.4cm] 
\textsc{\LARGE University}\\[2cm] % University name

{\large \today}\\[4cm] 

\vfill
\end{center}

\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image: titlepage]

You asked in a comment for the documentation:  If you have a TeX distribution installed on your computer, you can use `texdoc koma-script` or---if you use a online compiler---search the internet for file `scrguide.pdf` (German version) or `scrguien.pdf` (English version) or you can try [texdoc.net](http://texdoc.net/), but the versions are not always up-to-date.

Comment: @MaryStar You could just as well scrap that horrible Hrule. It is one of the wikibook deseases.

Comment: you could mention http://texdoc.net/, but the versions are not always up-to-date.